# how to create pandas dataframe based on any of columns above threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create new dataframe based on other dataframe. For example

```
column1    column2   column3   column4
   a          10        3         2
   b           4        4         3
   c           2        3         6
   d           3        8         2
```

and i want the output if any columns is above 5, so like this.

```
column1    column2   column3   column4
   a          10        3         2
   c           2        3         6
   d           3        8         2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it with `any`:

```
df[(df[['column2', 'column3', 'column4']] > 5).any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
column1    column2   column3   column4
      a         10         3         2
      c          2         3         6
      d          3         8         2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
df.loc[df.set_index('column1').gt(5).any(1).values]
```

This is especially useful if you have a large number of columns after `column1` and you don't want to manually type all the column names one by one.

Output:

```
  column1  column2  column3  column4
0       a       10        3        2
2       c        2        3        6
3       d        3        8        2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
threshold = 5
df1[(df1.select_dtypes(include='number') > threshold).any(axis = 1)]
```

You may change the threshold value also.